# In express delete working in res object but it should be req and if it work why it is working

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I am making simple SQL and express connections and doing an insert, update, and delete. Insert and update is working fine but when I started to delete using req.body I getting undefined in the body part

```
app.delete('/empdelete',function(res,req) 
    {
        console.log(req);
        db.query('delete from product.employee where id = ?', [req.body.id], function (err,rows){
            console.log(err);
            console.log(rows); 
            req.redirect('/');
        });
    });
```

and when i change to req to res it work fine so why it work on res it should be req

```
app.delete('/empdelete',function(res,req) 
    {
        console.log(res);
        db.query('delete from product.employee where id = ?', [res.body.id], function (err,rows){
            console.log(err);
            console.log(rows); 
            req.redirect('/');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your sequence of args in the callback is incorrect. The syntax should be as:

```
app.delete('/:route',function(req,res) 
    {
      console.log(req.body);
    });
```